# How to reset the meta store with Hive on Spark?

Tags: unit-testing, hive, apache-spark, derby, jdo

I want to reset the Hive Meta Store with Hive on Spark in a unit test.

So far, I've reconfigured the JDO to use a in-memory Derby DB:

```
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:derby:memory:metastore_db;create=true");
System.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName", "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

There seems to be no proper life cycle management for JDO in Hive, so Hive/JDO complains if I drop or shutdown the database.

Does anybody know of a way to reset the meta store so that each test case runs with a fresh, clean meta store?

Comment: Are you creating a new SparkContext in every test case? I'm not **sure** it helps but that may make things simpler.